# Как на чистом Си принять данные запроса, отправленные через XmlHttpRequest по http2 (h2)?

Tags: c, https

Запрос в JavaScript:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'www.example.com/?q=1', true);
  xhr.send();
```

Как принять данные в программе и как правильно ответить с точки зрения HTTP/2, чтобы клиент мог считать в xhr.responseText данные ответа?

Comment: то есть, Вы спрашиваете, как написать свой веб сервер с поддержкой http2?

Comment: Нет, сервер может гораздо больше, чем требуется для ответа на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое первое - надо изучить сокеты и попробовать [написать обычный http сервер](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/C-Web-Server) или ещё [один вариант](https://gist.github.com/laobubu/d6d0e9beb934b60b2e552c2d03e1409e). Без этого знания дальше двигаться не стоит. Также стоит пролистать статью [beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/translations/bgnet_A4_rus.pdf) о том, как работать с сокетами (она на русском языке).

Дальше, открыть [спецификацию](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) и статью на [хабре](https://habr.com/post/221427/) и внимательно прочитать. Также можно поискать [готовую реализацию](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations), но это если лень писать.

Теперь делаем предпоследний шаг. Берем любой работающий http2 сервер (например, nginx, вот даже готовый [докер](https://hub.docker.com/r/newhr/http2-server/)) и делает работающим клиентом (к примеру, curl или браузер) запрос, убеждаемся, что ответ ожидаемый. Паралельно запускаем [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) и наблюдаем за обменом.

Теперь дело осталось за малым. Берем сервер и просто модифицируем чтение запись. Если это просто тестовое задание, где нужно просто ответит на один известный запрос - чтение/запись можно даже и захардкодить.

Самое главное - это следить за тем, что бы не был использован tls (или другое шифрование) - это сильно усложнит начальный этап.

Comment: Вот tls мне как раз и нужен.

Comment: думаю, им стоит заняться, когда оно заработает без шифрования.

Comment: С tls будет даже в чем то проще, примеров от OpenSSL тьма, там есть набор упрощённых функций для реализации, можно глянуть другие SSL продукты, есть интерфейсы реализованные и попроще.